# Is there an equivalent of -compose mathematics in Imagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

I am trying to rewrite an Imagemagick script into Imagick. I am struck at a point where I want to write the following code piece to Imagick.

```
-compose mathematics
```

Could someone check whether there is an option? I don't find a -compose option like
imagick::COMPOSITE_MATHEMATICS in PHP

Comment: I suspect the expectation is that you would do the maths using PHP's maths functions and operators.

Comment: -compose mathematics applies the following to two images c1*A*B+c2*B+c3*A+c4. So you can break that down in some cases to separate -compose multiply, -evaluate add c, -compose plus to combine all the results. Not all uses of -compose mathematics will be separable, if any involve negative values that would make the sums negative, unless using HDRI compile of Imagemagick such as Imagemagick 7.

Comment: CONTINUED: If that does not work, then you will need to use -fx to do the equivalent of that operation and it will be considerably slower.

Comment: CONTINUED: Sorry, some of the separate operations include: -evaluate multiply c. I forgot to include those above.

Comment: Fred could you give your solution as an answer. Also, could you write the equivalent of -compose mathematics using the alternative method you have proposed using ImageMagick so that I can understand what you refer here?

Answer (score 0):

In Imagemagick command line, if you have two input images A and B

```
convert A B -define compose:args="a,b,c,d" -compose mathematics result

then

that means

a*A*B + b*B + c*A +d

so 

a*A*B is 

convert A B -compose multiply -composite -evaluate multiply a tmp1

b*B is

convert B -evaluate multiply b tmp2

c*A is

convert A -evaluate multiply c tmp3


a*A*B + b*B + c*A +d

convert tmp1 tmp2 -compose plus -composite tmp3 -compose plus -composite -evaluate add 100*d% result

where 100*d must be evaluated ahead of time
```

You will need to get the Imagick equivalents.

Not all uses of -compose mathematics will be separable, if any involve values outside the Quantum Range of your compile. So the be sure you need to use HDRI compile of Imagemagick such as with Imagemagick 7 default compile or recompile IM 6 with HDRI enabled.

If you cannot use HDRI, then if the separate operations do not work, then you will need to use -fx to do the equivalent and it will be considerably slower